# How can you size exported art for use in Google Presentations without having to resize?

Tags: export, presentation-design, google, art

How can I determine the exact size to export art for use in slides of Google Presentations without having to re-size once I bring them in to Presentation? I would like to create the original art at the same size as what I will use in Google Presentation so that I don't have to duplicate my efforts. I went into page setup and set the ration to 16:9, if you drop down to custom size the window will show you your current size in whatever measurement - say inches, which equals 10" w x 5.625" H. So I then set my document size in Coreldraw to that size with the hope that designing in that size in Coreldraw would yield an exact fit in Google Presentation without the need to resize - Keeping it simple. That did not work. Images were too large and required resizing. What am I missing?

Comment: Try working in pixels, instead of inches?  No need to work in inches, if you're only going to view this on a screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the exact pixel size of your slides by going to File > Page Setup. Change the dropdown here to Custom and the Inches dropdown to Custom, and your slide pixel dimensions will be displayed.

One you have these dimensions, any image you add that fits inside that space will not need to be resized. If you want a full-screen image, just use the full dimensions!

Comment: I wanted to export a slide in 4K resolution, but it seems to be a limit to 2500 pixels.